# HttpResponseCache and no internet connection

Tags: android, connection, httpresponse

Application should provide last data from server if it doesn't have internet connection. Is it good idea to use HttpResponseCache as instrument for saving all http requests to use them in offline mode?

For now, when I disable Internet connection, there is exception:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
```

Should I write data to the disk, and use it in offline mode?

P.S.
I configured HttpResponseCache, and use HttpURLConnection:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-stale=" + maxStale);
connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setUseCaches(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
```

Comment: Did you add this already in manifest:    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: Yes, yes, of course. Application with internet connection operates ok.

Comment: Yes. I'm using loaders with custom stale for responses, and crusial data store at fast storage: SharedPreferences. Ideal solution will be ContentProvider + Service.

Comment: Where did you configure **HttpResponseCache**?